# Members of Twilio Queue undefined

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am getting an error when attempting to access members of a queue.

I have tried both methods below for adding members to the queue in case I was mistaken about how the system worked. (I started using the Enqueue method)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <Response>
    <Dial>
       <Queue waitUrl="https://node.myserver.com:81/inbound/music">support</Queue>
    </Dial>
 </Response>
```

and

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <Response>
     <Enqueue waitUrl="https://node.myserver.com:81/inbound/music">support</Enqueue>
 </Response>
```

Both of these seem to work in adding the call to the queue and playing the hold music

I have also checked to make sure I have the correct SID for the queue

Running the code

```
 client.queues.list(function(err, data) {
       data.queues.forEach(function(queue) {
            console.log(queue.friendlyName + ": " + queue.sid);
       });
   });
```

give me the result

support: QUxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6

Yet when I have calls in the queue holding and try to extract data using an example right from the twilio API page at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member

```
 client.queues('QUxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6').members.list(function(err, data) {
     data.members.forEach(function(member) {
         console.log(member.Position);
     });
 });
```

I get the following error

```
 GET /inbound/call/agent 200 39.997 ms - 73

 /var/www/tcc/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                     throw e;
                           ^
 TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined
     at /var/www/tcc/routes/index.js:348:20
     at /var/www/tcc/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:1920:17
     at flush (/var/www/tcc/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
 17 Feb 14:02:42 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: After doing additional testing I can manually queue the resource page like you would using cURL and the data is displayed correctly there.

This error exists for queueing any information for a Queue except for its Sid

the Sid displays fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/StevenDStanton/f8c3d748e93466a7e4b8

```
 var https = require('https');
 var options = {
 host: 'api.twilio.com',
 port: 443,
 path: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + sid + '/' + queuesid + '.json',
 method: 'GET',
 auth: sid + ":" + auth,
 agent: false
 };
 var req = https.request(options, function(rex) {
   rex.setEncoding('utf8');
   rex.on('data', function (chunk) {
     var obj = JSON.parse(chunk);
     res.send(obj.current_size.toString());
   });
 });

 req.on('error', function(e) {
   console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
 });



 req.end();
```

Comment: I just found out you can also add .json to the end of the request to return a json object.